# RTCPeerConnection is not a constructor in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

The below code is working well in the browser console of the google chrome browser and in visualforce also.

console.log(new RTCPeerConnection({}))

[image]

but when I add the same console.log in the connected call back of my LWC page it throws below error

[image]

Do we need to do somehting extra to make it work in LWC also

Comment: I am guessing this relates to the [Lightning locker service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_service).

Comment: Yes it seems like locker service issue webRTC is not supported in the locker service

Answer (score 2):

RTCPeerConnection is not supported by Lightning Locker

[image: locker api viewer]

From Winter '22 on, you can activate next generation Lightning Web Security for LWC (beta) and see if that specific interface is supported (haven't tried). See more details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/09/learn-moar-in-winter-22-with-release-highlights-for-developers).